# how can i make a UI like this ... i mean these curves and the lines and stuff in react native

Tags: node.js, user-interface, react-native, nodejs-server

[image]

how can i make a good UI in react native like this? kindly help me out ...

Comment: It seems likely that this would be made with images, not drawn this way with code.

Comment: Look at themes from trusted templating sites, like https://startreact.com/